# how to get categories and subcategories with model classes from json

Tags: java, android, json

I have created a model class for category that i am getting from below json

```
    {
"currency": {
    "INR": "1.000000000000",
    "USD": "0.015400000000"
},
"category": [{
    "category_id": 3,
    "parent_id": 2,
    "name": "Gifts & Smiles",
    "is_active": 1,
    "position": 1,
    "level": 2,
    "children": []
},
{
    "category_id": 4,
    "parent_id": 2,
    "name": "Send To",
    "is_active": 1,
    "position": 2,
    "level": 2,
    "children": [{
        "category_id": 22,
        "parent_id": 4,
        "name": "India",
        "is_active": 1,
        "position": 1,
        "level": 3,
        "children": [{
            "category_id": 8,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Agra",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 1,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 6,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Ahmedabad",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 2,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 9,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Akola",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 3,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 10,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Allahabad",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 4,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 11,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Aligarh",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 5,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 12,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Ambala",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 6,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 13,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Amravati",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 7,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 15,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Amritsar",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 8,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 14,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Aurangabad",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 9,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 7,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Bangalore",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 10,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 16,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Baroda",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 11,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 17,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Bhopal",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 12,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 18,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Chandigarh",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 13,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 19,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Chennai",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 14,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "category_id": 21,
            "parent_id": 22,
            "name": "Delhi",
            "is_active": 1,
            "position": 15,
            "level": 4,
            "children": []
        }]
    },
    {
        "category_id": 23,
        "parent_id": 4,
        "name": "Abroad",
        "is_active": 1,
        "position": 2,
        "level": 3,
        "children": []
    }]
},
{
    "category_id": 20,
    "parent_id": 2,
    "name": "Gift Cards",
    "is_active": 1,
    "position": 3,
    "level": 2,
    "children": []
}]}
```

and this is my model class to get categories from json

```
public class ModelCategories {

public static ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

i know how to parse the json but my problem is how can i store sub-categories in model class i am new for this type of scenario.

so please help me...

Comment: Please explain more `how can i store sub-categories in model class` line

Comment: what json parser do you use?

Comment: i know the parsing technique very well but how can i store the sub-categories according to  their categories in model classes. I used the array lists to store the categories.

Comment: You should try this , http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ , It will create POJOs for you. You just need to make appropriate selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you have created a model like this ModelCategories.
If I have to work on this I will create a model named Category as:

```
  public class Category {
       String id;
       String name;
       int position;
       List<Category> subCategories;
  }
```

Comment: then how should i store multiple categories, those i am taking from json.

Comment: maintain a list of categories in your class: List<Category> categories;

Comment: ok but there is one more level for country. please help me in this scenario.

Comment: please specify where the country field is. I can't find it in your JSON.

Comment: please copy paste the my json here you will get idea http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: are you talking about currency?

Comment: in india sub-category there is child categories of states.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101064/discussion-between-sachin-mandhare-and-bhawna-raheja).